# Why does the Method of Successive Approximations for a Differential Equation work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, perturbation-theory

Time dependent [perturbation theory in quantum mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perturbation_theory_%28quantum_mechanics%29) is often derived using the Method of Successive Approximations for a Differential Equation.  I have not seen an explanation or  a more rigorous outline of proof as to why this should work?

Normally we start with this equation:
$$
i\hbar \dot d_f=\sum_n\langle f^0|H^1(t)|n^0\rangle e^{i\omega_{fn} t}d_n(t)
$$
and then we say that to zeroth order the RHS is 0. and then we plug that into the first order and so on, as outlined in Shankar:

> and as what $d_f(t)$ is. To *zeroth order*, we ignore the right-hand side of Eq. (18.2.5) completely, becasue of the explicit $H^1$, and get 
>   $$\dot d_f=0 \tag{18.2.7}$$
>   in accordance with our expectations. To *first order*, we use the zeroth-order $d_n$ in the right-hand side because $H_1$is itself of first order. This gives us the first-order equation
>   $$
> \dot d_f(t)=\frac{-i}\hbar\langle f^0|H^1(t)|i^0\rangle e^{i\omega_{fi} t} \tag{18.2.8}
> $$
>   the solution to which is, with the right initial conditions, is
>   $$
> d_f(t) = \delta_{fi} - \frac{i}\hbar\int_0^t \langle f^0|H^1(t')|i^0\rangle e^{i\omega_{fi} t'}\text dt' \tag{18.2.9}
> $$

But how could we explain why this should work more rigorously?

Comment: This might be better off on math.SE as I don't think the method is constrained to physics but works for any differential equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cleaning stuff up, here are your givens:
$$i\frac{\partial{|\psi(t)\rangle}}{\partial t}= {H(t)}{|\psi(t)\rangle},\quad{|\psi(t_0)\rangle}=|\psi\rangle$$
Now, I claim that this series is a solution:
$$|\psi(t)\rangle=\left(1+(-i)\int_{t_0}^tdt_1 {H(t_1)}+(-i)^2\int_{t_0}^tdt_1\int_{t_0}^{t_1}dt_2{H(t_1)H(t_2)}+...\right)|\psi\rangle$$
Check it, by differentiating by $t$, and noticing how $-iH(t)$ arises as a common factor. That's what is usually called a [T-exponent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential). And you are asking about the first term in the series.

Comment: I see that if you plug in the final solution they match, but I wonder if there is a more constructive or motivational approach?

Comment: @AimForClarity I doubt it. I mean, if you look carefully  at any DE solution procedure, you'll notice that there is always this "guessing a form of the solution" step. I can wrong on that, though, but this discussion definitely do not belong to physics.SE -- try math.SE instead.

Comment: thanks Kostya, i will also try MathSE

Answer (score 1):

For completeness I wanted to post an excerpt here from  Grynberg's Introduction to Quantum Optics which I though also answers the questions a bit more formally in terms of mathematics;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The series expansion, known as the Dyson series, is formally correct. However, to prove that it actually converges can be a major problem.